# How to get the last 10 query run on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0, node.js

I am using mongoose driver in my Node.js app and I want to know what queries mongoose run behind the scene when I call available function on mongoose model.

e.g. I am saving a signup information for a user using mongoose `create` function and as per its definition: it should create the document in the database with the provided information. It returns a document to the caller, so I am curious to know whether it run extra query to get the returned document or it makes it from the provided information. In the first case it will take a network bandwidth for the already available information so I want to avoid this by using any other function but I don't think it is working like this.

Anyway, please suggest me how can I see the last 10 queries that hits MongoDB Database?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762264/log-all-queries-that-mongoose-fire-in-the-application

Comment: This will help me. Thanks. Also, it will be great if the same thing we can do at MongoDB side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the database side, you can enable [Auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/auditing/), but at this time, only available on MongoDB Enterprise.